# Is the following complex number "finite"?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

This is my first question on this forum, so, forgive me in advanced if I make some type of syntax error...

I am working on applying a theorem which involves computing a definite integral, and showing that the number obtained from this definite integral is finite, i.e., "< $\infty$".

However, the result I obtain, which I am quite sure of is ArcTanh[100] = 0.0100003 - 1.5708 I. My question is:
Is: 0.0100003 - 1.5708 i < $\infty$?

My first inkling was that if the components a,b of a + bi are finite, then the complex number should be finite, but, I am not sure how the notion of finiteness applies in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: There are no infinite complex numbers. (Let's not delve into the Riemann sphere for OP.) And what you have there is a complex number.

Comment: Usually when we talk of definite integrals in Complex analysis, we mean $\left|\int f(z)dz\right|<\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course that complex number is less than infinity.  Any complex number can be most easily compared to "infinity" (an arbitrarily large number) by simply calculating its magnitude, that is the square root of the sum of the squares of its $x$ and $y$ components. Of course, if you CAN calculate that magnitude, it is less than infinity.  On the other hand, it is easy to draw curves (I switch to a POLAR representation) which manifestly tend toward infinity as their angle $\theta$ grows large.  Such a curve would be, for example, $R = \theta$.  The limit of $R$ as $\theta$ approaches infinity IS infinity, and we can picture this simply as a spiral that keeps on going, and keeps on going...

Comment: Howdy Tom, welcome aboard.  Check this out:  type "\$\theta\$" and it looks like $\theta$.  And "\$r = \theta\$" gives $r = \theta$!  Ain't that cool?  That's $\LaTeX$!  Cheers!  Nice answer, ***endorsed!!!***

Comment: Robert Lewis, this special-character method didn't work for me.  But I keep the Windows Character Map handy for that purpose. θ